# Почему не работает фоновый режим в Android 8.1.0

Tags: android, cordova

Пишу приложение на Cordova. Мне нужно, что бы оно работало в фоне. Поставил плагин - [ссылка](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

Все работает, только не на версии 8.1.0. На этой версии приложение "падает", то есть выбивает сообщение, что приложение остановлено.

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Код ошибки

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: 
java.Iang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: 
Notification(channel=null pri=-2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null 
defaults=OxO flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread. java:1794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6635)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
com.android.internal.os.Runtimelnit$MethodAndArgsCaller.ru n(Runtimelnit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit.main(Zygotelnit.java: 823)
```

Comment: В логах написана причина, читайте

Comment: в том и проблема, что я не понимаю, в чем ошибка - http://joxi.ru/Vm6oew0F47PZX2

Comment: Поместите текст ошибки в сам вопрос (текстом, а не картинкой)

Comment: Почему cordova? Хотя выбор ваш, портируйте сами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531742/startforeground-fail-after-upgrade-to-android-8-1. Проблема в том что нет notification channels. Для старой версии норм работало вот так: val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this). Сейчас нужно вот так: val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId ). И плюс реализация. Реализация не обязательно - только что проверил. Главное впишите channelId, например: "myChannel"